# Why does this infinite scrolling list sometimes scroll itself?

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I created an infinite scroll proof of concept using [choo](http://choo.io), a JavaScript framework that uses [bel](https://github.com/shama/bel/) and [nanomorph](https://github.com/yoshuawuyts/nanomorph) to patch the DOM. It works, but sometimes if you scroll in it, it seems to keep scrolling itself until it reaches the end. You can interrupt it and then it will work as intended, until it takes control again.

[Demo](https://curved-shame.glitch.me/)

The primary source code is `view.js`:

```
module.exports = function view (state, emit) {
  const rowHeight = 41
  const tableHeight = 500
  const startRowIndex = Math.floor(state.scrollTop / rowHeight)
  const maxVisibleRows = Math.ceil(tableHeight / rowHeight) // round up
  const maxRowIndex = state.contacts.length - 1
  const endRowIndex = Math.min(maxRowIndex, startRowIndex + maxVisibleRows)
  const remainingRows = state.contacts.length - endRowIndex
  const rows = state.contacts.slice(startRowIndex, endRowIndex + 1)
  const topPadding = startRowIndex * rowHeight
  const bottomPadding = remainingRows * rowHeight

  const onScrollDebounced = debounce(onScroll, 25)

  console.log({startRowIndex, endRowIndex, topPadding, bottomPadding})

  return html`
    <body>
      <table class="table ${prefix}" onscroll=${onScrollDebounced}>
        <tbody>
          ${paddingRow(topPadding)}
          ${rows.map(tableRow)}
          ${paddingRow(bottomPadding)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  `

  function onScroll (evt) {
    emit('scroll', evt.target.scrollTop)
  }

  function paddingRow (padding) {
    if (!padding) return ''

    return html`
      <tr style="height: ${padding}px">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    `
  }

  function tableRow (contact) {
    return html`
      <tr>
        <td>${contact.id}</td>
        <td>${contact.first_name}</td>
        <td>${contact.last_name}</td>
        <td>${contact.email}</td>
        <td>${contact.gender}</td>
        <td>${contact.ip_address}</td>
      </tr>
    `
  }
}
```

You probably don't need it, but the state comes from `store.js`:

```
module.exports = function store (state, emitter) {
  state.contacts = require('./data.json')
  state.scrollTop = 0

  emitter.on('scroll', (scrollTop) => {
    state.scrollTop = scrollTop
    emitter.emit('render')
  })
}
```

How is this self-scrolling loop happening, and is there any way to prevent it?

Thanks!